# Invalid path for js bundles in nginx served react app

Tags: reactjs, nginx, build, react-router, production

So I have a SPA that I built using Create-React-App. It works completely fine for local dev, and I wanted to deploy the built app using nginx.

I set up my `Dockerfile` and `nginx.conf`, and at first all seemed to run fine. But then, I noticed weirdest issue.

Most of the app is working fine, but when I try to access a nested URL directly (i.e. not by navigating to it through the app -> This works fine. Problem happens only when I access the URL directly, or refresh the page), there are errors in the console/network while fetching the built files. Say I'm accessing `localhost:3000/app/potato`, I see my browser is trying to access files from `localhost:3000/app/static/js/2.ebff4827.chunk.js` (instead of `localhost:3000/static/js/2 .ebff4827.chunk.js`)

Accessing `localhost:3000/app` works fine, but `localhost:3000/app/` (with trailing /) has the same weird behaviour.

As a result, the browser fails to load the page...

Here's my `nginx.conf` (although I don't believe this to cause my error, as I set it up with a blank CRA and it worked fine https://github.com/piaverous/cra-nginx-demo):

```
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;                 
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any clue on what could be causing the issue ? I'm totally at a loss here

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out this problem came from my webpack build. 
In my `package.json`, i had `homepage: "./"`, which caused the path resolving issues.

Just removing this field seemed to fix this issue ! Nginx config was fine :)

Comment: The docs on that homepage variable are atrocious. This post saved my day. But it's so far apparently typical of using react. Milking yaks and crushing stones is basically the order of the day. Why a setting that when set as they recommend would break a very basic build. Who knows.